# django have the ability to login with phone or email

Tags: django

I want to create a django custom user model such that i can have my users login with either phone or email.

**This is my proposed solution**

```
class ExtendedUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phonenumber = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, null=True ..)
    email = EmailField(unique=True, null=True ..)
    ...
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'pk'
```

so now while login, i can do something like this

```
if cleaned_data['phonenumber']:
   u = User.objects.get(phonenumber=cleaned_data['phonenumber'])
   authenticate(username=u.pk, password=cleaned_data['password'])
   ...

elif cleaned_data['email']:
   ...
```

I am not sure whether it is possible to put `USERNAME_FIELD` as `pk`.
We can easily put a UUIDField if that's not possible.

Is the proposed solution fine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unique constrain for Email and Phone are good. Also, I would set USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'.

Then, I think you should try to create a custom authentication backend. You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

Like Django says: When somebody calls django.contrib.auth.authenticate(), Django tries authenticating across all of its authentication backends.

Then in your custom authentication backend you can ask for Email or Phone:

```
class CustomAuthenticationBackend:

    def authenticate(self, request, email_or_phone=None, password=None):
        try:
             user = User.objects.get(
                 Q(email=email_or_phone) | Q(phone=email_or_phone)
             )
             pwd_valid = user.check_password(password)
             if pwd_valid:            
                 return user
             return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I think it can work. Let me know!!

Best regards.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my signup process is also optional, the user can signup with either EMAIL or PHONE. Hence, I am a little skeptical on putting the USERNAME_FIELD to be PHONE / EMAIL...

Comment: Why do I need such a login process? I host multiple domains on the same server and different clients ask for different signup processes

Comment: Ok. So, users can choose between signup with email or phone and according to the decision, they are redirected to a specifics subdomain that know how to deal with each case then you create the accounts, is that correct? 

If the above is correct, how do you manage the login? Do the users have to choose between login with email or phone and then they are a redirected to different subdomains to manage the login?

Means, that you are running multiple Django instance?

Comment: Nope, I have set that 'x' domain has email process and 'y' domain has phone process. Now when the request comes from 'x' domain, then I show them the email signup page. I have this part sorted out in the view.

Comment: So its using a single django instance to serve on multiple domains, essentially giving the feel of separate servers to my clients. This way if i sell my product to a new client, I just add the domain rules from the django admin and good to go..

Comment: Looks like i can use a custom user model that doesn't have a username field if i write my own custom backend :) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD

Comment: Yes, exactly. Definitely, you will have to write your custom authentication backend to be able to identify the users by email or phone and login them.  I thought that you were using a microservices approach, this is why I asked about the subdomains.  So this approach can work!! :-)

Comment: what is that microservices approach you talk about?

Comment: I thought you had two Django instances and one Authentication Server. Let's Imagine you are using Nginx and you have rules to route your traffic. Depending on the URL you will forward each request to a specific Django Instance and each instance knows have to display each Signup Form and create users. When someone wants to login, the  request will go to either of Django instances and then to the Authentication Server. In the Authentication Server you will have to know how to handle the login either by email or mobile. I was imagine that. Did you create your Custom backend Authentication?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163416/discussion-between-marcos-schroh-and-dev-aggarwal).

Answer (score 0):

```
django login take two argoman : reqeust and user query so when we get this two things we can login. django authenticate searching in the user model and when user in found ....


def log_in(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated is True:
    return redirect('/home/')
if request.method == 'POST':

    u = request.POST.get('_phone_')
    p = request.POST.get('_pass1_')

    if '@' in u:
        user_check = authenticate(request, email=u, password=p)
    else:
        user_check = MyUser.objects.get(phone= u) # search in our model and find user with phone  


    if user_check is not None:

        user_check.last_login= datetime.now()
        user_check.save(update_fields=['last_login'])

        login(request, user_check)

        return redirect('/home/')

    else:
        return HttpResponse('bad request')
else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```